# How to remote publish a blog portlet entry with liferay 6.1.1, without having the status DRAFT on the live application?

Tags: liferay, blogs, liferay-6

I have set 2 machines with liferay 6.1.1 and I'm trying to remote publish a blog portlet entry. 
The settings I made in Control Panel -> Site Settings -> Advanced are correct as I managed to publish the entries to the machine I consider "the live instance", but it ends up being in the state of Draft.

How to perform the remote publishing in order for the blog entry to remain in the state of "published", as it is on the machine from which I'm doing the publication (and not in the draft state)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a liferay issue. I found out that the server dates of the staging and live applications were out of sync. Once I set the same date to both servers everything worked perfectly.